# Android Studio doesn't identify "on" keyword for Dart extension methodes

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

My Android Studio doesn't recognize `on` in the context of Dart extension methods:

```
void main() {
  print('42'.parseInt());
}

extension NumberParsing on String {
  int parseInt() {
    return int.parse(this);
  }
}
```

It shows a red line beneath it and when I hover over, it says: `Undefined class 'on'.`. As a result, it also doesn't recognize the receiver `Type` after `on`, which in my case is `String`.

However, it still compiles, runs the code and produces the expected result. So I guess it should be a silly Android Studio editor issue, and it's super annoying when coding.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

[image: Hovering over the ON]

analysis_options.yaml:

```
include: package:pedantic/analysis_options.1.8.0.yaml

analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - extension-methods
    - spread-collections
```

More info:

- Flutter plugin version: 44.0.2
- Dart plugin version: 192.7761
- Android Studio version: 3.6.1
- The error for `extension` is for allow-experiment.
- In `try/catch` context, my Android Studio recognizes `on` as a keyword.

Comment: post your `analysis_options.yaml` file - do you have `extension-methods` in `enable-experiment:` ?

Comment: @pskink Added my `analysis_options.yaml` to the question.

Comment: and what do you have in `environment: sdk:` in pubspec.yaml? `">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"`?

Comment: @pskink I have `sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"` in my `environment` in the pubspec.yaml, So let me increase it to 2.7.0 and check again...

Comment: @pskink Yup, that was the culprit! After increasing the version, I had to do the "flutter upgrade" as well, and after a long upgrade, it got fixed. Thx, please provide the answer, below so I can mark it.

Comment: your welcome, feel free to post a self answer then (now i am not sure if it needs to be 2.7 or 2.6 since i saw different info on the web... - you could check both version numbers)

Comment: I tried 2.6, it works as well, but anything below it, shows some sort of IDE errors for extension methods. :thumbs-up:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @pskink in the comments, the problem was my `pubspec.yaml` which had `sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"` for `environment`. I needed to raise it to be at least `sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"` to solve the problem. (Obviously `2.7.0` works too.)

After doing that, I had to touch the `flutter upgrade` as well. Seems it was pretty old as it relatively took a long time to upgrade. After that, every IDE warning vanished in the thin air!